# Printing Different Sized PDF

Tags: print-design, pdf

I would like to know the best way to set up my designs for print by others.
I will be sending my clients PDF's of designs I have created specifically for them.  They will either print them on their own or bring to print center, most likely Staples type.

1. I need to send in PDF
2. Clients needs to be able to choose size - especially poster size.
3. Prints need to look good

I have created a design in Photoshop & saved it as a PDF, however when I try to print it as Poster I am only seeing an 11x14 size??

Thanks any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should **NOT** send a PDF so a non-expert user do whatever he wants. Send some pre-defined sizes, so the user just uses one file or another.

A PDF file is physically based. Of course, you can just use the adobe reader to scale it to fit the page, but you can have some unexpected margins, or the person will print a miniature, or a pixelated print, or a very large file size.

The settings must be tweaked in the moment of printing (in the adobe reader print dialog). And you can not expect everybody doing that. You already having problems there.

I'm not sure what version this screen capture is, but there you can see the "shrink to printable area" option.

[image: Print dialog]